# camel cxf endpoint route creation issue

Tags: apache-camel, camel-cxf

I am getting a below exception while creating an endpoint using camel cxf.
Camel stops when it tries to create service from WSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://soap.ussd.product.web.com/USSD_NW-v1.0}UssdSoapNW from WSDL: http://127.0.0.1:8280/WebSoap/services/UssdSoapNW?wsdl

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.initializeWrapping(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:438)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.initializeWSDLOperation(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:259)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeWSDLOperations(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:692)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.initializeWSDLOperations(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:303)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:438)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint.createClient(CxfSpringEndpoint.java:116)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.doStart(CxfProducer.java:76)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.SynchronousDelegateProducer.start(SynchronousDelegateProducer.java:66)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2869)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1097)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1058)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:405)
```

Route Configuration:-

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="ussdEndpoint" address="http://{{USSD_SOAP_IP_ADDRESS}}:{{USSD_SOAP_PORT}}/WebSoap/services/UssdSoapNW"
            wsdlURL="http://{{USSD_SOAP_IP_ADDRESS}}:{{USSD_SOAP_PORT}}/WebSoap/services/UssdSoapNW?wsdl"
            serviceClass="com.web.product.ussd.soap.u ssd_nw_v1_0.UssdSoapNWPortTypeV10"
            endpointName="ws:UssdSoapNWSOAP11port_http"
            serviceName="ws:UssdSoapNW"
            xmlns:ws="http://soap.ussd.product.web.com/USSD_NW-v1.0/">
            <cxf:properties>
                <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO"/>
                <entry key="synchronous" value="true" />
            </cxf:properties>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Comment: I am not sure, can you try removing the space you have in the serviceClass attribute.

Comment: Can you check the WSDL file? From the stack trace it looks like your WSDL is not right.